# How to know to which value I should define _POSIX_C_SOURCE?

Tags: c, posix

Let's say for instance I want to use the structure `timespec`, which is defined in time.h. According to the manpages I only need to include time.h. But when compiling in c99, this isn't enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct timespec abcd;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   return 0;
}
```

According to the info I find online (not in the manpages), I need to add this:

`#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`

So I have a few questions:

- How do I know to which value I need _POSIX_C_SOURCE to be equal? I found multiple values online.
- Why does the placement of this definition influence the compilation? (cf . infra)

`#include <stdio.h>`

`#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`

`#include <time.h>`

`struct timespec abcd;`

`int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
`{`
`return 0;`
`}`

`$ gcc test.c -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c99 -o test`
`test.c:9:25: error: field ‘time_last_package’ has incomplete type`
`struct timespec time_last_package;`

compiles well:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
....
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably don't need to add that define. But see [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html). You could compile with `-std=gnu99` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). You could be interested by using [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) in your project

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sorry I explicitly want to compile with c99. You are offering a workaround not a solution to the problem I am explaining :)

Comment: But that `feature_test_macros` page is still useful to read. I am not sure that your problem has a well defined solution in general. If you are standard picky, you need to know which precise POSIX standard you want to follow

Comment: The Linux man page for `nanosleep(3)` specifically mentions that feature test macro `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L` is required for `nanosleep` and `struct timespec` via glibc. Sadly, this is not in some of the other man pages for `nanosleep`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - How do I know to which value I need _POSIX_C_SOURCE to be equal? I found multiple values online.

There is one value per POSIX standard definition. So you can use any value which:

1. defines the functionality you need
2. is supported by your hosting OS

Best is to use the lowest value that meet both those criteria.

> - Why does the placement of this definition influence the compilation?

POSIX says :

> **System Interface Chapter 2. Section 2 The Compilation Environment**: A POSIX-conforming application should ensure that the feature test
>   macro _POSIX_C_SOURCE is defined before inclusion of any header.

Otherwise it may leads to wrong/incompatible included definitions... Defining it **before** any include ensure that all is under the same POSIX version...

Recommended reading : [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition, 2 - General Information](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html)

Answer (score 1):

The other answer gives nice background. But, it's also possible to define this at the compiler level so you don't have to put it in your source. With `gcc` and glibc at least, the command-line option

```
-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L
```

is enough to ensure that `nanosleep` and `struct timespec` are available if you include `<time.h>`.